# Problema con Unity 5.5.0p3 and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity2d

Estoy haciendo un juego con 'Unity version: 5.5.0p3 (64 bit)' para plataforma iOS, lo construyo y abro con 'Xcode version: 8.2.1 (8C1002)' del no aparece Warnings, pero al correr en un device aparecen 329 Warnings (se repiten muchos Warnings), estos se resumen en los siguientes:

- Unused function 'InitCrash' -> CrashReporter.mm
- Unused function 'InitObjCUEHandler' -> CrashReporter.mm
- Unused variable 'iBound' -> mscorlib_ArrayTypes.h
- Undeclared selector 'onUnityUpdateViewLayout'-> UnityView.mm
- Undeclared selector 'createUnityViewImpl' -> UnityAppcontroller.mm
- Undeclared selector 'createViewHierarchyImpl' -> UnityAppcontroller.mm
- Code will never be executed:

  - Bulk_Generics_0.cpp
  - Bulk_Generics_1.cpp
  - Bulk_Generics_2.cpp
  - Bulk_Generics_3.cpp
  - GenericMethods0.cpp 'extern' variable has an initializer -> Il2CppCompilerCalculateTypeValues.cpp

Favor una ayuda porque con estos Warnings no me aceptarán en 'App Store'.

Comment: Creo que las advertencias estan bastante claras, para el Undeclared selector, puedes leer **[esto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508084/5622844)**.

Comment: Gracias pr escribir NaCI, en esto tengo inexperiencia ¿Como puede sacar los Warnings de "Bulk_Generics_X.cpp"? Entiendo que todo esto lo genera il2cpp pero no se "como" eliminar estos Warnings/Alertas.

Comment: He publicado varias aplicaciones usando Unity en el app store y siempre tienen todas tantisimos warnings y nunca me las han tirado por ese motivo. Aún así cuanto más reciente es la versión de Unity menos warnings suele tener.

Comment: Gracias por tu experiencia @JuanBayonaBeriso, soy nuevo en Unity, estaba preocupado que en App Store me rechazaran mi app, jamás había tenido tantos. :)